# What are the different ways to measure mass, for mechatronics

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanical

I’m trying to build a small mechatronic device and want to know the different ways of measuring mass. The ones that I’ve found so far are vibration and directly measuring mass using weight or a scale.

Comment: Consider variations on a balance. Comparing mass to a known mass.

Comment: Measure volume and multiply with density? Hang from a spring with known spring constant and measure deflection are two that come to mind